# UISearchBar in UINavigationController's UINavigationBar not clickable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a `UISearchBar` and set it to my `UINavigationController`'s `titleView` property. The left button of the navigation bar is null, and the search bar displays properly.

However, any touches on the search bar are ignored. The cancel button does not receive taps, and the search bar text field does not respond to taps either.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: show your code to add search bar

Comment: manually enable navigation bar's userInteraction.may be that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that I was instantiating the `UISearchBar` with

```
[[UISearchBar alloc] init]
```

thus giving it a 0x0 size. The `UISearchBar` was displayed correctly, so I didn't think that the frame could be the reason.